# how to transfer data from one component to another using service in angular

Tags: angular

I want to send an array of employee id to another component using service. I have 2 components- component1 and component2. From component1 I am selecting employees using checkboxes.
Here is my component.ts file from where I am sending array of employee id to service.

*component1.ts file*

```
      checkbox_selected = []
      ischecked: boolean;
     constructor(private attendanceService: EmployeeService, private router: Router,
     private fb: FormBuilder) {  }

     onChange(checkbox: any, isChecked: boolean) {
     console.log("checkbox")
     this.checkbox_selected.push(checkbox)
     this.id = checkbox
     this.ischecked = isChecked
     console.log(this.checkbox_selected)
     }
    show(){
    if(this.ischecked == true){
   this.router.navigate(["./component2"])
   this.attendanceService.my_employee_id(this.checkbox_selected);

    }
```

*service.ts file*

```
     export class EmployeeService {
      my_employee_id(id) {
      console.log(id)
     return this.emp_id;
     }
     }
```

In my service file, I am getting the array of employee id.
How can I get these array of employee id in another component??

Answer (score 0):

Please read the angular documentation or do some research before asking.
Please read about [Angular component interaction using service](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service)

On a high level what you want is... [see below]

#### Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmployeeService {

  // Observable string sources
  private selectedEmpSub = new Subject<string[]>();

  // Observable string streams
  public myEmpSubj$ = this.selectedEmpSub.asObservable();

  // Service methods
  myEmployeeId(empIds: string[]) {
    this.selectedEmpSub.next(empIds);
    this.selectedEmpSub.complete();
  }

}
```

#### Component-1

```
this.attendanceService.myEmployeeId(this.checkbox_selected);
```

#### Component-2

```
this.attendanceService.myEmpSubj$.subscribe(empId => {
    this.empId = empId;
    console.log(this.empId);
});
```